# nrpe buffer size exceed

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I'm working on nagios nrpe and i am trying to implement my own nrpe plug-ins, the problem is my plugins output has more then 1024 bytes of char, which is more then the nrpe packet buffer size.

```
A packet carrying the NRPE payload has a fixed layout where in order of occurence in the packet the following fields are defined:

[2 Byte int16_t] – Version number
[2 Byte int16_t] – Type (Query/Response)
[4 Byte u_int32_t] – CRC32 Checksum
[2 Byte int16_t] – result code (OK, WARNING, ERROR, UNKNOWN)
[1024 Byte char] Buffer
```

Is there any way to increase the size of this buffer??????

Comment: NRPE 3 has a 64K buffer. Also, you can re-adjust the definitions of the buffer sizes in the header files and recompile in older versions, if you so desire. Look in `common.h.in` (Make sure to change it here if you're going to copy this code to multiple machines to configure and compile, since the `common.h` file is generated from the `.in` file. Look for: `#define MAX_INPUT_BUFFER`. Hope this helps.

Comment: first of all thanks for your valuable answer .................................................. i have one more issue,my plugin is a shell script its working fine but if i replace this shell script with c executable it always shows unable to read the output...... can u have any idea how can i resolve this issue .

Comment: Not without seeing the code. That sounds like a different question altogether.